# If $b_j>0$ for all $j$ and $\sum b_j$ diverges, let $s_j = \sum_{l=1}^j b_l$, what can we say about the convergence of $\sum \frac{b_j}{s_j}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

See the title. I have no clue how this can be done. Gut feeling tells me it probably diverges? But since this is math, unfortunately gut feelings don't count... Can someone give a hint? I want to try to work this out myself.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The $s_j$ are eventually all  greater than $1$.

Comment: So then $\frac{b_j}{s_j} < b_j$ eventually. But $\sum b_j$ diverges so I don't know if this helps... Am I on the right track?

Comment: Hmm, I must have misread the question. I thought you wanted to show $\sum_j b_js_j$ diverges.

Comment: I want to show $\sum_j \frac{b_j}{s_j}$ diverges (or converges, I don't actually know which is it). I'm thinking it probably diverges since if we take $b_j=1$ for all $j$ then the resulting series is the harmonic series, which diverges.